# OnItemClickListener - changing the click area

Tags: android, android-listview

This is probably poor phrasing of the question, but I'm not sure how else to explain it. I am using DevBytes' expanding listview in my app (http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewExpandingCells.zip).
I wanted to further customize the listview item and add 2 buttons. Having done that, the listview no longer expands or registers clicks. All I did was add 2 buttons in the listview item layout xml, with no other code additions or changes.

How can I make the OnItemClickListener react again, and only when the textview part of the item is clicked?

Comment: You could able to set the listeners in the adapter itself. or use AdapterView.onItemClickListener();

Comment: @Quanturium, thanks for that link. android:focusable is what I needed.